# Why my maven project does not pick-up the jar from nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I am on `Redhat`, using `jenkins` with `Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.12.0-01`.

What I am trying to achieve is to download all the jar from nexus.
What, I have accomplished.
Successfully installed `nexus 2.12.0-01`

This is the content of my maven `setting.xml`

```html
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0                                                                                                                   
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
 

    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
        <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
            <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>

            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

**Successfully installed 3rd party jar for Ojdbc5 in nexus**
[image]

**content of my parent pom**

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <modules>
    <module>Project1</module>
    <module>Project2</module>
 </modules>
 
 <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>my-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>

    <repository>
        <id>my-releases</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>

</distributionManagement>
</project>
```

In the above `pom.xml` there are two projects define. When I build using jenkins, The first project get successfully build. but the second one throws error.

> Failed to execute goal on project project2: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.abc:project2:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure
>   to find com.oracle:ojdbc5:jar:11.2.0.1 in
>   http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the
>   local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Please see the project2 `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>project2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>

 <distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>thirdparty</id>
    <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>

  <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ojdbc 5 dependency provide by nexus-->

        <dependency>
         <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
         <artifactId>ojdbc5</artifactId>
         <version>11.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- That is creating problem -->
```

Please do not worry about the  above `pom.xml` I have removed lot of dependency from pom to reduce the size of question. The pom structure is Ok.

Now coming to question. Have I missed any configuration, Why I am getting

> Failed to execute goal on project gsdataprocessor: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.globalss.batch:gsdataprocessor:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc5:jar:11.2.0.1 in http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

This error.
Please help

Update 1: As suggest by user `sanigo` I have added Thirdpary repository  the Public Repository Group

Update 2: Below is the screen-short which shows oracle ojdbc5 is available is public repository.
[image] 
[image]

Comment: Oracle dependencies are not in any kind of public repository available so you need to manually install them into your repository on your nexus....

Comment: Have you added your `3rd Party` repository in the public group in your Nexus? Furthermore removed the folder for `com/oracle/*` from your local repository and retry....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public (Public Repository Group) is mirror of "*", so you should add http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty(Thirdparty repositoy) to the Public Repository Group, you can do this in the Public Repository Configuration tab. Then you can use `mvn -U clean install.`

Comment: How do I add Thirdparty to the public Repository group?? can please explain.. Sorry for being so dumb

Comment: @Roman Zenka  as suggested I have added my Thirdparty repository to public group, please see Update1. But still I am getting the same error

Comment: Is the Oracle artifact in the 3rdparty repository? My understanding is that you might have to upload the artifact manually, if Oracle does not provide them openly (you probably need to agree to some licensing before you download from Oracle, meaning the process cannot be automated by Maven).

Comment: yes you are right. the oracle artifact is in the 3rdparty repository. and I have uploaded oracle jar manually in 3rdparty repository..is my configuration is ok?

Comment: You use mvn -U clean install, "-U" tell maven to do a force updating.

Comment: Thanks , Now Its working I just did `clean` and it worked

Comment: The key point is not "clean". It is the time span. You will need use -U to force maven to retry a failed download as maven will not retry within update interval.